# clear error messages next to inputs

Tags: jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery validation plugin and trying to figure out how I can remove the default error messages next to the inputs on the form.

Here is an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dman100/jJsSG/29/)

I'm display the number of invalid fields in the div at the top and highlighting my input field.

The error message next to the input "This field is required" I want to remove.  If the field is valid, I want to add a green tick mark showing  the field is successfully validated.

Here is my script I've been toying with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function(){
        var validator = j$('[id$=Details]').validate({
            invalidHandler: function() {
                j$("#error-message").html('<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.event, 'images/error-icon.png')}" width="32" height="32">').append(" Please correct the entries highlighted below. " + validator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid.");
            },
            success: function(label) {
                //label.replaceWith('<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.event, 'images/success-icon.png')}" width="16" height="16" class="validated">');
            }
        });

        j$('[id$=Email]').rules("add",{
            required: true,
            email: true
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Does this help explain?
Thanks.

Comment: The plugin already clears the errors next the inputs, _by default_.  Why not start by using the plugin as intended and then slightly modify the default classes to display the red border & checkmarks?

Comment: Also, these types of questions can be useless if you leave out the HTML.  I suggest that you create a jsFiddle demo, or at the very least include the HTML in your question so a working answer can be constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the jQuery Validate plugin already automatically shows and clears errors dynamically, so maybe you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.   Without seeing your HTML or fully knowing why you're taking your approach, this is a generic example that will point you in the right direction.

This can easily be modified to display checkmarks instead of background colors.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2yqL/)

**HTML:**

```
​<form>
    <input type="text" name="myfield" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            myfield: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });

});​
```

**CSS:**

```
.valid {
    background-color: green;
}
.error {
    background-color: red;
}​​​
```

---

**EDIT:**  as per OP's jsFiddle

Change `.replaceWith()` to [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and clear out the `#error-message` `div` on success, and `.insertAfter(element)` to place the check-mark next to the element.  And finally, add `return false` to the `errorPlacement:` function to block placing any errors at all.

```
success: function(label, element) {
    label
        .html(
            '<img src="images/success-icon.png" width="16" height="16" class="validated">'
        )
        .insertAfter(element);
    j$("#error-message").text('');
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    return false;
},
```

**Working demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/jJsSG/34/

Comment: Thanks for replying to my post and the tip to use JSFiddle.  I included an example that might help clarify.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks Sparky! The green tick mark image does display when the fields are validated, however, the error message text still displays when the fields are invalid.  Is there a way to clear the error message text?  I only want the error message to display at the top and not next to the input fields.  Thanks again! Regards.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! And, thank you for the tip on JSFiddle!

Comment: @Dman100, You're welcome. If this solves your problem, please "accept" my answer by clicking the check-mark.